# I need to add dependency condition on params in my powershell script what is the best way to do it?

Tags: powershell

```
param (
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true, HelpMessage="action")]
[ValidateSet('deploy','remove')]
[string]$action = "list",
[Parameter( Mandatory=$false, HelpMessage="zip File")]
[ValidateScript({
        if(-Not ($_ | Test-Path) ){
           throw "File or folder does not exist"
        }
        if(-Not ($_ | Test-Path -PathType Leaf) ){
            throw "The Path argument must be a file. Folder paths are not allowed."
        }
        if($_ -notmatch "(\.zip)"){
            throw "The file specified in the path argument must be a zipFile"
       }
        return $true 
    })]
[System.IO.FileInfo]$zipFile
)
```

These are the params in my script and I want to add a condition in here like zipFile param should be a mandatory only if the action is deploy, Can we add this may be using dynamic param? would something like this work?

```
    param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, HelpMessage="action")]
[ValidateSet('deploy','remove')]
[string]$action = "list",
[Parameter( Mandatory=$false, HelpMessage="zip File")]
[ValidateScript({
        if(-Not ($_ | Test-Path) ){
           throw "File or folder does not exist"
        }
        if(-Not ($_ | Test-Path -PathType Leaf) ){
            throw "The Path argument must be a file. Folder paths are not allowed."
        }
        if($_ -notmatch "(\.zip)"){
            throw "The file specified in the path argument must be a zipFile"
       }
        return $true 
    })]
[System.IO.FileInfo]$zipFile
    )
    DynamicParam {
         if ($action -eq "deploy"){
         $zipFile.Mandatory = $true
           }
         }
    process {
    #Here comes script
    }
```

Comment: What you need to look into is 'parameter sets' that enable you to define different combinations of parameters with different requirements per set